# traffic control (tc) filter not working

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, traffic-shaping, tc, bandwidth-control

i am using Debian and am trying to limit the upload-bandwidth on an ip basis.

The configuration is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
tc=/sbin/tc

$tc qdisc del dev eth0 root 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
$tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress 2> /dev/null > /dev/null

$tc qdisc del dev tun0 root 2> /dev/null > /dev/null
$tc qdisc del dev tun0 ingress 2> /dev/null > /dev/null

$tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 30

$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 5.0mbit burst 6k
$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 2.0mbit ceil 4.5mbit burst 2k prio 1
$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 2.0mbit ceil 4.5mbit burst 3k prio 2
$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 0.5mbit burst 1k prio 3

$tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10
$tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
$tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10

$tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.1 flowid 1:10
$tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.2 flowid 1:20
$tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.4 flowid 1:30
```

The "setup" seems to be fine:

```
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 1 u32 chain 0 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 1 u32 chain 0 fh 800: ht divisor 1 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 1 u32 chain 0 fh 800::800 order 2048 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:10 not_in_hw 
  match c0a80101/ffffffff at 12
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 1 u32 chain 0 fh 800::801 order 2049 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:20 not_in_hw 
  match c0a80102/ffffffff at 12
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 1 u32 chain 0 fh 800::802 order 2050 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:30 not_in_hw 
  match c0a80104/ffffffff at 12
```

But I end up having all clients being in 1:30 despite the filter:

```
+---(1:1) htb rate 5Mbit ceil 5Mbit burst 6Kb cburst 1600b 
     |    Sent 18121225 bytes 29841 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 1926 requeues 0) 
     |    backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
     |
     +---(1:10) htb prio 1 rate 2Mbit ceil 4500Kbit burst 2Kb cburst 1599b 
     |          Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
     |          backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
     |     
     +---(1:20) htb prio 2 rate 2Mbit ceil 4500Kbit burst 3Kb cburst 1599b 
     |          Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
     |          backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
     |     
     +---(1:30) htb prio 3 rate 500Kbit ceil 500Kbit burst 1Kb cburst 1600b 
                Sent 18121225 bytes 29841 pkt (dropped 23532, overlimits 27820 requeues 0) 
                backlog 244086b 117p requeues 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I was able to apply the filtering rules by using iptables:

```
$tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip handle 2 fw flowid 1:20
$ipt -t mangle -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.2 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

It results in the traffic from 192.168.1.2 being put into 1:20:

```
+---(1:1) htb rate 5Mbit ceil 5Mbit burst 6Kb cburst 1600b 
     |    Sent 34671556 bytes 40595 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 8591 requeues 0) 
     |    backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
     |
     +---(1:10) htb prio 1 rate 2Mbit ceil 4500Kbit burst 2Kb cburst 1599b 
     |          Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
     |          backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
     |     
     +---(1:20) htb prio 2 rate 2Mbit ceil 3500Kbit burst 3Kb cburst 1599b 
     |          Sent 26070590 bytes 17443 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 10466 requeues 0) 
     |          backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
     |     
     +---(1:30) htb prio 3 rate 500Kbit ceil 500Kbit burst 1Kb cburst 1600b 
                Sent 8600966 bytes 23152 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 23146 requeues 0) 
                backlog 57060b 70p requeues 0
```

As of now it seems that the u32 filter does not work.

Comment: I copied your setup in a dummy environment (using 3 local source IPs, not routing) and I get filter hits for each of the 3 source IPs with tc alone. I'm using kernel 5.10 rather than 4.19 though, in case that matters. Are you sure you are not using a MASQUERADE rule? it would be invisible from the filter/FORWARD chain but very visible from tc at the end of the pipe: never matching 192.168.1.x

Comment: I am indeed using masquerade on two external interfaces:

```
$iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @[A-B](https://serverfault.com/users/217515/a-b) who made me aware of the reason behind tc not filtering.

I do use MASQUERADING on all external interfaces and it seems that those rules are applied before tc can filter the packets. This results in the following recommendation:

**If you are using a MASQUERADE-rule on the outgoing interface you need to use the fw-filter from traffic-control and mark the packets using iptables.**

This might seem obvious to the more experienced users but its not mentioned anywhere and (at least for me) its hard to find out.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
tc=/sbin/tc
ipt=/sbin/iptables

$tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 30

# shape general uplink speed
$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 5.0mbit burst 6k
$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 2.0mbit ceil 4.0mbit burst 2k prio 1
$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 2.5mbit ceil 4.0mbit burst 3k prio 2
$tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 0.5mbit ceil 1.0mbit burst 1k prio 3

# stochastic fairness
$tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:10 handle 10: sfq perturb 10
$tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:20 handle 20: sfq perturb 10
$tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:30 handle 30: sfq perturb 10

# filtering on eth0
$tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip handle 10 fw flowid 1:10
$tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip handle 20 fw flowid 1:20
$tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip handle 30 fw flowid 1:30

# marking packets via iptables
$ipt -t mangle -I FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.2 -j MARK --set-mark 20
$ipt -t mangle -I FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.4 -j MARK --set-mark 30
$ipt -t mangle -I FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.21 -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

Those settings result in packets from the mentioned sources (**-s**) being assigned to the classes defined above.